# Complexity analysis of the printParty method

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
void printParty(int N) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= N; i *= 2) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j += 1) {
         System.out.println("hello");
      }
   }
}
```

I sort of get that this code's complexity is N but more clarification would be appreciatd.

Also I had another thought which was

```
void printParty(int N) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j *= 2) {
          System.out.println("hello");
      }
   }
}
```

I think the last code snippet would have complexity of NlogN....
My friend says it's the same as the one above.

Can you help me visualize this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: You are correct in both cases. The first code is `O(n)`. The second is `O(nlogn)`.

Your friend is mistaken because he failed to understand that the first code has exponential decay - while the second one does not, which is very significant in complexity analysis.

Detailed explanations below.

---

First code:

```
For i = 1  -> j runs 1 times
For i = 2 -> j runs 2 times
For i = 4 -> j runs 4 times
...
for i = 2^k -> j runs 2^k times.
```

This means, the complexity of the first code is:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^k + ... + 2^(logn)
```

This is [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with:

```
a = 1
r = 2
N = logn + 1
```

The [sum of geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) series is given as:

```
a(1-r^N)/(1-r) =
1 * (1-2^(logn+1))/(1-2) = 1*(2^(logn+1) - 1) = 2*2^logn - 1 = 2n - 1
```

And it is easy to see this is in `O(n)`.

---

Second code:

```
For i = 1 -> j runs log(1) times
For i = 2 -> j runs log(2) times
For i = 3 -> j runs log(3) times
....
For i = k -> j runs log(k) times
```

If we sum it we get

```
log(1) + log(2) + log(3) + ... + log(k) + log(n)
```

This is completely different from the previous one. There is no geometric decay, so the complexity is not linear.

An easy way to see it is:

```
log(1) + log(2) + log(3) + ... + log(k) + log(n) >
> log(n/2) + log(n/2 + 1) + log(n/2 + 2) + ... + log(n/2 + n/2) >
> n/2 * log(n/2) >=
>= n/2 * log(n) - n/2*log(2)
```

Since this is in `O(nlogn)`, the complexity of this code is in `O(nlogn)`

(Another way to show it is by going to `log(n!)`, which is known `O(nlogn)`)